# Subversion and LDAP integration

Tags: svn, ldap

i have subversion under linux machine which configured against LDAP.
i will need to migrate this machine and svn repositories to work against different LDAP server.
this new LDAP server will includes new username.
in order for this migration to be easier for the developers i wanted to add some alias meshanism to the old username, so they will will be able to "commit" with their old username.

i though it will be possible using authz but i cant make it work and i sarted to think i didnt understand the idea for this authentication method.

so what i have?
under my http.conf i have Location for my repo with the following parametres:

```
 DAV svn
  SVNPATH <mydata>
  AuthBasicProvider ldap
  AuthType Basic
  AthzLDAPAuthoritative on
  authzSVNAccessFile <mydata>
  authName <mydata>
  authLDAPURL <mydata>
  AuthLDAPBindPassword <mydata>
  AuthLDAPBindDN <mydata>
  require valid-user
```

so i've added to that file the parameter "authzSVNAccessFile 'path' and added some alias for my AD user under the autz file. such as:
[aliases]
myaliasname = CN=My First and Last Name,OU=Users,DC=MyDomain,DC=com

now i though that whenever i will try to svn commit with "myaliasname" it will recognize that im actually using "My  First and Last Name" user...
the actual result is its just doesnt recognize this use....
i'm out of the scope?
this aliases feature is only for the access control file for permissions?

thanks alot,

Chen